# How to add all words with length more than X to the list from all X files in Directory?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace FunkcjaSpilit
{
    class Program2
    {
        static int _MinWordLength = 7;

        static void Main()
        {
            DirectoryInfo filePaths = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\project_IAD");
            FileInfo[] Files = filePaths.GetFiles("*.sgm");
            List<int> firstone = new List<int>();

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                int longWordsCount = CalculateLongWordsCount(file, _MinWordLength);
                string justFileName = file.Name;
                firstone.Add(longWordsCount);
                Console.WriteLine(("W pliku: " + justFileName) + " liczba długich słów to " + longWordsCount);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(firstone.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int CalculateLongWordsCount(FileInfo file, int _MinWordLength)
        {
            return File.ReadLines(file.FullName).
                Select(line => line.Split(' ').Count(word => word.Length > _MinWordLength)).Sum();
        }
    }
}
```

I this code at line `firstone.Add(longWordsCount);` I'd like to add all words with length more than 7 to the list, but after running this code, `firstone.Add(longWordsCount);` adds only sum of **files** in directory (**not** the sum of **all words with length more then 7** in all .sgm files in directory).

How can I fix it?

Expected results:

```
firstone.Add(longWordsCount);
```

should add all words with length more than 7 to the list from all files in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're print the list length in the line:

```
Console.WriteLine(firstone.Count);
```

It should be:

```
Console.WriteLine(firstone.Sum(f => f));
```

**EDIT**:

But as you don't really use the list at all, I would suggest you replace the foreach with this, to avoid saving a list that is not actually used.

```
int wordsWithTheRequiredLenghtCount = 0;
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    int longWordsCount = CalculateLongWordsCount(file, 7);
    wordsWithTheRequiredLenghtCount += longWordsCount;
    Console.WriteLine(("W pliku: " + file.Name) + " liczba długich słów to " + longWordsCount);
}
```

If you don't really need to print the file name in front of the file word count. And just want the global word count, the @Dmitry Bychenko solution is way better.

But he deleted it, so I will just replicate it here since I found it very clever.

```
var words = Directory
.EnumerateFiles(@"D:\project_IAD", "*.sgm")
  .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))
  .SelectMany(line => line.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Where(word => word.Length > minWordLength))
  .Count();
```